# Stories.map is not a function, nextJS takes wrong variable

Tags: javascript, next.js

so my problem is, that I have two variables called stories, one of which is from the React lib and the other one in my code. The problem is, that it passes the wrong stories variable, which then gives me the error: "TypeError: stories.map is not a function", because its taking the React stories variable and not the variable I created myself. Down below is the picture where I explain it with a graphic.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaAOS.jpg)

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";

import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
import Error from 'next/error'

class Index extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps() {
        let stories
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://node-hnapi.herokuapp.com/news?page=1')
            stories = await response.json()
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            stories =  []
            
        }

        return { stories };
    }

    render() {
        const {stories} = this.props

        if(stories.length === 0) {
            return <Error statusCode={503}/>
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>hacker next</h1>
                <div>
                    {stories.map(story => (
                        <h2 key={story.id}>{story.title}</h2>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Index;
```

Comment: These are two different variables. The variable you want is local to another function, you can't use that variable on the `render` method.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, but the problem was the API link.
I changed it to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and it worked. So the problem was the fetching process.